# In what way[s] does Buddhist doctrine agree with or contradict Anekāntavāda?

Tags: jainism

What do Buddhists - modern day and historical - think of [Anekāntavāda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anekantavada)?  There is this cryptic remark by Dharmakirti:

> With the differentiation removed, all things have dual nature. Then,
> if somebody is implored to eat curd, then why he does not eat camel?"
> The insinuation is obvious; if curd exists from the nature of curd and
> does not exist from the nature of a camel, then one is justified in
> eating camel, as by eating camel, he is merely eating the negation of
> curd.

I could summarize it at such: *the truth/reality is complex and many-sided.* How does the quote apply to the subject matter?  The truth/reality being complex and many-sided doesn't seem to end suffering, but at least it gives individuals some solace. Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess this is off-topic, like "What do Buddhists think of [some aspect of Christian doctrine]"?" would be off-topic. More on-topic would be, "In what way[s] does Buddhist doctrine agree with or contradict  Anekāntavāda?"-- so that the topic then would "Buddhist doctrine" at least as much as it is Anekāntavāda. And even though that might be on-topic it might not be answerable -- a reason for a site-specific "topic" on Stack Exchange is so there's a "community" of people who may know that subject and answer questions on it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Mahavir was more Courageous than Tathagata on this matter!

Let's say we have a bowl of milk. If we expose it to various conditions the milk can change into curd or buttermilk or cheese or butter. Now let me ask you a question, is milk permanent or not ? If it's permanent then it can't change, isn't it? If it is not then what is changing?

Adi Shankaracharya said there's is Brahman which is absolute and permanent, milk is illusion,not permanent, it's just projection on Consciousness hence is changing and is permanent at same time. His philosophy of Vedanta is for *permanence*. He sees the *substance* not process.

Siddharth Gautam said there is nothing permanent only change it there, nor is the milk permanent nor it's derivatives nor the absolute. His philosophy is of *change*. He sees the process not substance.

Mahavir was courageous, he ended this powerful bull (the paradox) by holding it's both horns! His philosophy is of *anekantva* plurality. He acknowledged both substance and process.

Vardhaman Mahavir said in some way Truth is permanent in some way it is not. In this way He synthesized both point of view, the have *jiva* to represent permanent aspect of Truth and *ajiva* to represent non permanent aspect.

They deny God or Brahman but have concept of soul! This and similar things makes their approach slightly complex and hence it is not as popular as Buddhism, which is straight forward and simple, though in some way the jain teaching of anekantva is very powerful and rational.

Dharmakirti was great intellectual and logician but I think he forgot that something which is applicable for part may not be applicable for whole. If his logic fits on given analogy it doesn't mean it is true for Absolute Truth as well. The analogy presented by him requires knowledge of logic and is subject of scholarly investigation, hence saying anything on it by me is not good.

Coming to last question that 'Anekāntavāda doesn't end suffering but gives solace....' on which I think nothing can *end* suffering. Even Buddha catched disease in his old age, cause of suffering was there but he didn't suffered because he had attained to something which made him immune of suffering. Nirvana, Moksha, kaivalya or Enlightenment is nothing but just a mere understanding that whatever may come we can remain in bliss without getting absorbed in external circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

Reality is that all compounded phenomena are impermanent. Reality is that all compounded phenomena are suffering. And reality is that all phenomena are not-self.

Nibbana is the ultimate Truth. It is unborn , uncreated , unformed , unoriginated, unbecoming. It is the escape from born , created , formed , originated and becoming.

All the above Truths are immutable whether Buddha arises or not.

Jains however believe reality is complex and many sided. Jains do not speak of the suffering or the cessation of suffering. Buddhism is all about the teaching of suffering, cessation of suffering and path leading to the cessation of suffering.

Buddha is superior to Jains.